# Problem in Uploading file on ftp server using commons net 3.0 api (org.apache.commons.net )

Tags: java, ftp, apache-commons-net

I am trying to save text file on ftp server which is in my drive and it has data, the file is successfully stored there, but the file is completely empty even it has data.

The following is my loose attempt.

```
FTPClient client = new FTPClient();
    FileInputStream fis = null;


    try {
        client.connect("ftp.drivehq.com");
    } catch (SocketException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        client.login("zaheerkth", "mypassword");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    String filename = "c://ss.txt";
    try {
        fis = new FileInputStream(filename);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        client.storeFile(filename, fis);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        client.logout();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        fis.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may need to do `client.enterLocalPassiveMode()` if you are running behind a firewall or NAT.

EDIT: local passive is probably what you want.

Comment: thankyou. it works :). so i got solution to upload a file after 3 days :(.

Comment: [Sarif Sissddharth](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1223381/saraf-sissddharth) [asks for more details](http://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/226263): where should he put that call?

Comment: Call that before you call `storeFile` and it should work, assuming you don't have any other networking issues.

Answer (score 1):

This is my code please check it in this i want to store file name in database & to store file in ftp server in this code i am able to store the file there is no content in that file it stores as a blank file.

```
     String email="";    
     int i=0;    

 int count1=0;
     boolean isMultipart = ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(request);
     if (!isMultipart) {
      } else {
   FileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory();
   ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload(factory);
   List items = null;
   try {
   items = upload.parseRequest(request);
   } catch (FileUploadException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
   }
   Iterator itr = items.iterator();
   while (itr.hasNext()) 
   {
   FileItem item = (FileItem) itr.next();
   if (item.isFormField())
   {
      String name = item.getFieldName();
      String value = item.getString();
      if(name.equals("email"))
           {
           email=value;
                }




     } else
   {
     try {

     String itemName = item.getName();
     itemName = new java.io.File(itemName).getName(); 

     String fname="";
     String ext="";
     int mid= itemName.lastIndexOf(".");
     fname=itemName.substring(0,mid);
     ext=itemName.substring(mid+1,itemName.length()); 

     if(ext.equals("doc") || ext.equals("docx") ||ext.equals("txt")    ||ext.equals("pdf")){  
     count1=1;
     FileInputStream fis = null;


    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
                Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/beehivej_beehivejobs", "root", "root");
                Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
                String s="SELECT idfile FROM file ORDER BY idfile DESC LIMIT 1";
                ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery(s);
                while(rs.next()){i=Integer.parseInt(rs.getString(1));}
                String sql="insert into file (filename,emailid) Values ('"+itemName+"','"+email+"')";
                int in=stmt.executeUpdate(sql);

      FTPClient client = new FTPClient();

      try {

      client.connect("ftp.xyz.com");

      } catch (SocketException e) {
      // TODO Auto-generated catch block
      e.printStackTrace();
      } catch (IOException e) {
      // TODO Auto-generated catch block
      e.printStackTrace();
      }
      try {
      client.login("username", "password");


      } catch (IOException e) {
      // TODO Auto-generated catch block
      e.printStackTrace();
      }


      try {
      fis = new FileInputStream(itemName);
      count1=1;
      } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
      e.printStackTrace();
      }
      try {

      String name="Beehive_Resume"+i+"."+ext;
      client.enterLocalPassiveMode();
      client.storeFile(itemName, fis);

     count1=1;
     } catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
     }
    try {
    client.enterLocalActiveMode();
    client.logout();
    count1=1;
    } catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
    fis.close();
    count1=1;
    } catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
    }


    }else
    {
      response.sendRedirect("Account/reg4.jsp?email="+email+"&msg=This is not Supported  File");
    }
    }catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    count1=1;
    }
    }
    } 
    }
    if(count1==1)
    {
     response.sendRedirect("Account/Home.jsp?email="+email);
    }
```